# SpringBoot não reconhece aplication.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, maven, spring-jpa

Minha aplicação não reconhece meu aplication.properties na primeira vez, tenho que excluir e fazer de novo sempre que crio um workspace. Meu principal problema é que ele acaba gerando um valor padrão para a URL do meu banco H2, em vez do que eu coloquei nas propriedades. O arquivo está assim:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true 
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
spring.datasource.name=database
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

O problema é muito abstrato e como tem poucas informações na pergunta é difícil identificar o problema com precisão, porem aqui estão algumas etapas que você pode seguir para tentar resolver esse problema:

1. **Verifique a localização do arquivo `application.properties`**: Certifique-se de que o arquivo `application.properties` está localizado no diretório `src/main/resources` da sua aplicação Spring Boot. Esse é o local padrão para os arquivos de configuração.
2. **Verifique a formatação do arquivo**: Verifique se o arquivo `application.properties` está formatado corretamente, sem erros de sintaxe ou espaçamento inadequado. Cada propriedade deve estar em uma linha separada e seguir o padrão `chave=valor`.
3. **Limpe o cache e reconstrua a aplicação**: Às vezes, problemas de cache podem fazer com que as alterações nas configurações não sejam refletidas imediatamente. Tente limpar o cache do seu IDE ou build tool (por exemplo, Maven ou Gradle) e reconstrua a aplicação.
4. **Use o arquivo `application.yml` em vez de `application.properties`**: Em vez de usar o arquivo `.properties`, tente usar um arquivo `.yml` para definir suas configurações. A sintaxe é mais amigável e menos propensa a erros de formatação. Certifique-se de que o nome do arquivo seja `application.yml` e que as propriedades estejam corretamente indentadas.
5. **Verifique a prioridade das configurações**: O Spring Boot permite que as configurações sejam definidas em várias fontes, incluindo `application.properties`, arquivos `.yml`, variáveis de ambiente e propriedades do sistema. Verifique se nenhuma outra configuração está sendo aplicada e substituindo as suas definições.
6. **Verifique se não há configurações em código**: Às vezes, as configurações também podem ser definidas diretamente no código Java, o que pode anular as configurações do arquivo de propriedades. Certifique-se de que não existam anotações ou trechos de código que definam as configurações de banco de dados.
7. **Verifique as dependências do projeto**: Certifique-se de que suas dependências do Spring Boot e do H2 estão atualizadas para as versões mais recentes. Às vezes, problemas de compatibilidade podem causar comportamentos inesperados.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!! No fim das contas o problema era com o cache do eclipse mesmo!

Answer (score -3):

tente usar dessa forma, com base de conexão para o H2 DataBase e descrição de comandos SQL:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true